# Determine an image's MIME type from BLOB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, gd, mime-types

I'm storing thousands of images in a database in their binary format. I would like to determine the MIME type with PHP GD instead of using another column in the table.

What's the best way to do this without reading and writing to a temporary image file?

Comment: Please show the code how you would do it if there is a temporary file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [getimagesizefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php)

Comment: So simple, yet I never came across this function searching google. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a little bit old, but I was looking for a solution to figure this out on a BLOB from mysql and this is the way that worked for me.  I hope it helps someone else as well.  I don't know which way is best for performance, but it is worth testing.

```php
$finfo    = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mimeType = $finfo->buffer($myBlobHere);
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP only asked about image types. For image types, `getimagesizefromstring()` works well, but `finfo` works also well for other file types. Unfortunately, `finfo` is not available on all servers. It is included since PHP 5.3.0, but is often disabled on Windows systems. Therefore, I chose to first use `getimagesizefromstring` and if this cannot detect the mimetype, I check for the `finfo`-class, and in case it exists, I try finfo.

This is the combined solution:

```php
$imagesize = getimagesizefromstring($blobVal);
if($imagesize!==false && isset($imagesize['mime']))
    $mimetype = $imagesize['mime'];
elseif(class_exists('finfo'))
{
    $finfo    = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mimetype = $finfo->buffer($blobVal);
}
else
    $mimetype = "application/octet-stream";
```

Here, I am using a default mimetype as fallback, you might want to adjust this.

**Note**: Using `finfo`, you might want `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` instead of `FILEINFO_MIME`, as the latter also contains the encoding, whereas `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` only returns the mime-type. In my case, I use `$mimetype` in the http content-type header, where the encoding is helpful.